# Forward port 514 to 5514 only from specific source ip with firewalld

Tags: iptables, centos7, port-forwarding, firewalld

I've been trying to find a way to forward traffic from a specific ip, eg 10.17.1.3 on port 514 to port 5514 with firewalld on CentOS

This works:

```
  <masquerade/>
  <forward-port to-port="5514" protocol="udp" port="514"/>
  <forward-port to-port="5514" protocol="tcp" port="514"/>
```

Doesn't work:

```
  <masquerade/>
  <rule family="ipv4">
    <source address="10.17.1.3"/>
    <forward-port to-port="5514" protocol="udp" port="514"/>
  </rule>
```

Which was addded with:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='10.17.1.3' forward-port protocol='udp' port='514' to-port=5514"
```

Is there any way to achieve port forwarding only for a specific source ip with firewalld?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, when selecting traffic by source address, you should avoid using rich rules to select by source address, and instead create a new firewalld zone which matches traffic from the relevant source addresses.

For example:

```
firewall-cmd --new-zone=syslogsources --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --zone=syslogsources --add-source=10.17.1.3
firewall-cmd --zone=syslogsources --add-forward-port=port=514:proto=udp:toport=5514
```

And after you have confirmed it works, save it:

```
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

Comment: sudo firewall-cmd --new-zone=syslogsb
usage: see firewall-cmd man page
=> Option can be used only with --permanent.

sudo firewall-cmd --new-zone=syslogsbc --permanent
=> success

sudo firewall-cmd --zone=syslogsbc --add-source=10.17.1.3
=> Error: INVALID_ZONE: syslogsbc

Comment: @willemdh Yes, you need to add `--permanent` when making the zone. You also need to reload the firewall before adding rules to the zone. See the edited answer.